# Mathematica is able to compute an indefinite integral but not the corresponding definite one

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to compute the following definite integral in Mathematica:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[3]/Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 + 12*u^2 - 24*\[Mu]]], 
       {u, -Sqrt[1 + 8*\[Mu]]/2, Sqrt[1 + 8*\[Mu]]/2}]
```

Only for some specific case of Mu Mathematica seems to be able to compute it. The "funny" things are that:

- if I keep the integral indefinite, it returns me a solution (quite ugly, but at least...)
- if I give precise values for the boundary (e.g, u=+-1/2), after a long time it just returns the definite integral without any result
- if I additionally specify a precise value of Mu (so it knows Mu + boundary of integration), in one lucky case it is able to directly give me the result for the definite integral; this does not match with the value I would obtain by using the fundamental theorem of calculus (i.e. substituting the values of Mu and u in the ugly formula and taking the difference).

Has any of you an idea about what the problem could be? I would like to also point out that the square roots are always well definite for the values I consider.

Thank you.

Comment: There is a [Mathematica Stack-Exchange site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com); you should ask your question there.

Comment: you need to specify the asumption mu>-1/8 (at least)

Comment: Ok thank you. (The assumption on mu I was making already).

Comment: Actually you need `Assumptions -> {-1/8 < \[Mu] < 1/24}`, but even then no joy. Second the advice to try m.s.e.